# event not found when inverting interfaces selection (!interface) in IPTables

Tags: iptables

When I am trying to apply an `iptables` rule on all interface but one, I am trying this, but I get this shown error, could some one help me in that please?

PS. it works without (!) mark, but of course not the case I want, but I mean that the interface name is correct.

```
XXX@YYY:/home/Server$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i !br-3404fb184b60 --dport 1234-j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.3:1234
-bash: !br-3404fb184b60: event not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash` the `!` character is used for [history substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html#History-Interaction). You need to escape it to prevent this.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i \!br-3404fb184b60 --dport 1234-j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.3:1234
```